# Different communicating patterns in TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, wireshark, tls1.2

I used `Wireshark` to monitor packages of some websites, but found that there are such many communicating patterns of TLS 1.2.

The first one is a generic one:

```
Client: Client Hello
Server: Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done
Client: Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
Server: Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
```

Second one is as followed:

[Wireshark1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiiQn.png)

I'm just confused with why `Certificate` and `Server Hello Done` was in another package. Who demand server to do that? For what reasons?

After multiply refreshing page, I got the third one:

[Wireshark2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seoU5.png)

Only 3 packages in handshake? A lot of processes were missed, was it because the information was cached? And how about the pre-master key?

Thanks for the answering!

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstandings: The "packages" are created by the dissectors of Wireshark. This does not necessarily means that they have been sent in three packages by the server.

Comment: Packet. The word is packet, not package. The second one got split somehow by the sender or a router, and the third is an abbreviated handshake due to session resumption. There is nothing here to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS is a protocol over TCP, i.e. over a streaming transport protocol. For transport the data stream gets split into packets and thus it can happen that the ServerHelloDone is contained in one packet or in another or even split over two packets. Since the sizes are visible in your second example but not in the first it is unknown why the difference is exactly but it might be caused by the size of the certificate(s) contained in the handshake.

As for the third example: this is simple a TLS session reuse, i.e. it continues an older session and thus no sending of server certificate or similar is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answering! You guys are great!